# Get POST request body in Vite server.proxy["/api"].configure

Tags: proxy, configuration, vite

I am migrating a project from Webpack to Vite and have run into an issue with proxying requests to one of the endpoints in the ASP.NET MVC backend.

Due to circumstances of the existing project, I need to handle certain calls manually - such as on initial page load of login page, check whether user is already authenticated and redirect to the main page.

I am trying to figure out how to use `server.proxy.configure` to handle these requests. I am managing fine with the `GET` requests, but I cannot seem to receive the `POST` request's body data.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```js
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://my.local.environment/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        configure: (proxy: HttpProxy.Server, options: ProxyOptions) => {
          proxy.on("proxyReq", (proxyReq, req, res, options) => {
            if (req.method === "GET") {
              //handle simple get requests. no problems here
              //...
            } else {
              const buffer = [];
              console.log("received post request");
              proxyReq.on("data", (chunk) => {
                console.log("received chunk");
                buffer.push(chunk);
              });
              proxyReq.on("end", () => {
                console.log("post request completed");
                const body = Buffer.concat(buffer).toString();
                
                const forwardReq = http.request(
                  {
                    host: "https://my.local.environment",
                    port: 443,
                    method: "POST",
                    path: req.url,
                    headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json",
                      "Content-Length": data.length,
                    },
                  },
                  (result) => {
                    result.on("data", (d) => {
                      res.write(d);
                      res.end();
                    });
                  }
                );

                forwardReq.on("error", (error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                });

                forwardReq.write(data);
                forwardReq.end();
              });
            }
          });
        },
        secure: false,
      },
    }
  }
```

The problem is that neither `proxyReq.on("data", (chunk) => {` nor `proxyReq.on("end", (chunk) => {` ever actually trigger.

Additionally, `req.body` is undefined.

I have absolutely no idea where I am supposed to be getting the `POST` request's body.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a different question about the `bypass` option and this gave me the solution I was looking for. Ended up only handling the specific `GET` requests that I need to handle locally instead of forwarding to my deployed environment, and everything else gets handled automatically by vite.

```js
"/api": {
  target: "https://my.local.environment/",
  changeOrigin: true,
  agent: new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true,
  }),
  bypass(req, res, proxyOptions) {
    if (req.method === "GET") {
      //... here I get what I need and write to the res object
      // and of course call res.end()
    }
    //all other calls are handled automatically
  },
  secure: false,
},
```